# Are questions about the content of a Software Engineering portfolio on-topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have several questions about the content and requirements of a software engineer portfolio. For example:

- What kind of code examples are interesting?
- Which content is expected from a student applying for programming job?
- Is it a good idea to provide (very) long comments to your code?
- How to properly present projects, when the "outcome" is nice, but the code isn't?
- ...

Is it allowed to ask a question containing some of the questions above?
Or will this be off-topic/to broad/primarily opinion based?

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) would be a good home for a lot of these questions I think.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Next time I'll try to consult the chat first!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How are coding samples helpful when dealing with workplace issues?

I think it will be off topic.  Questions that require code to be useful have multiple sites to choose from ( code review, stack overflow, software engineering to name a few ).

Comment: That's a good point, thanks!

Comment: I agree, those look like multiple questions for multiple communities.